# 'Classifying with k-Nearest Neighbors' for not-number parameters

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have a fact data with set of parameters and some value that correspond to this parameters. 
For example:

```
Street     Color     Shape      Value
-------------------------------------- 
Versky     Blue      Ball         10
Soll       Green     Square       5
...
```

Now I need a create a function which get set of parameters [Holl, Red, Circle] and returns the predicted 'Value'.

If my parameters were the numbers I could use 'Classifying with k-Nearest Neighbors' algorithm, but they weren't.

Which machine-learning algorithm can I use to solve this task ?

Comment: Is `value` any 'number'? or is it a number from a predefined set? If it's any number, you are looking on *regression* and not *classification*.

Comment: The function must find k-nearest records in my data and return average between their values.  For example, three the same parameter is better than two the same ones.  It will be fine if I can set the weight for each parameter.  I know that I can create it by myself, but I am wondering if there is a standard solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that nearest neighbor is finding the nearest neighbor according to some distance metric. While indeed euclidean or similar metrics are widely used, any distance metric can be fine.

You can use a variation of [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance):

```
Let x[i] be the i'th feature of vector x
Let the number of features be n

    d(x,y) = Sum { (x[i] == y[i] ? 0 : 1) | i from 0 to n }
```

The above is a distance metric which is basically a variation of hamming distance where each feature got its unique alphabet.

Comment: Instead of counting 1 per discrepancy, you can indeed use a weight.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It should be carefully looked at, it has to be a distance metric { i.e. (1) `d(x,y)=d(y,x)`, (2) `d(x,y) >= 0`, (3) `d(x,y) + d(y,z) >= d(x,z)` }, so you need to chose it wisely

Comment: Actually there is no real reason why the cost function needs to be a distance. All you need is a total ordering on the set and any scalar function can do, with the loose requirement that "the smaller the better". The properties of the distance do not play a role in the definition of kNN.